# Call object property from within a callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

I have an async.series() calling a function from another javascript object:

**main.js**

```
var object1 = require('./object1');
var object1 = require('./object2');

async.series([
    object1.myFunction1,
    object2.anotherFunction
]);
```

**object1.js**

```
module.exports = {

  function1: function(callback){

    async.each(someArray, function(item, cb) {
        function2(item);
      }, function(err){
          if(err) return callback(err);
          callback();
      });
  },

  function2:function(item, callback){
    //Do something
  }
};
```

This code does not work because function2 is undefined inside the callback. I tried to put

```
var refToFunction2 = this.function2
```

at the beginning of function1. It works if we call directly function1, but here function1 is called by async and for some reasons: this = undefined.

Is there a clean way to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could setup your **object1.js** file in the following way:

```
var async = require('async');

function function1(callback){
  async.each(someArray, function(item, cb) {
    function2(item);
  }, function(err){
    if(err) return callback(err);
    callback();
  });
}

function function2(item, callback){
  //Do something
}

module.exports.function1 = function1;
module.exports.function2 = function2;
```

You should now notice that `function1` and `function2` are defined globally in the file. This means they can be called inside of each other freely.